# Is it possible to update google form questions according to the answers submitted?

Tags: api, google-forms

My professor asked me to create a google form that will allow students to opt for subjects/topics or recommend a topic of their choice. For example, the form would look like this:

```
        Courses Offered
    
Professor A
     o Topic A1
     o Topic A2

Professor B
     o Topic B1
     o Topic B2

Already recommended
     o SomeOtherTopic

Suggest a topic
_________________ (short answer text)
```

(o here represents radio button for selecting option)

Now, if a student suggests some topic then it should be added under the 'Already Recommended'
section. Also, a professor can volunteer for a recommended topic (if he/she knows about it) and hence the topic should then shift from 'Already Recommended' to the Professors list of offered courses.

I am beginner and have once used google sheets API using gspread. But I have no clue if such dynamic google forms can be created. If they do then is it possible to execute them using python or do I have to learn something new?

Comment: When you want to create the form for using dynamically, I think that to use the HTML custom form instead of Google Form is suitable. But I cannot understand about `execute them using python` and your detail goal. So I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks and no need to apologise, my English is also poor(^^'). I get your point about the custom HTML form but I wanted to use google forms because they can help me store data in google sheets (which I think I can also do with a custom form). By 'execute them using python', I meant to ask if there is some python library like 'gspread' that can help me to create a dynamic form. But it seems like JavaScript is much better for these aspects. My goal is to create a form that will allow students to choose as well as RECOMMEND subjects. Once recommended, the subject should appear in the form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sure, please ask me all the questions you have regarding my goal. I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your question soon.

Comment: No need to apologize (^^'). I am grateful that you approached me. I think I will find the alternatives soon. My aim is to create a form that can add new single choice options based on the previous answers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My aim is to create a form that can add new single choice options based on the previous answers.`, I could understand this. In this case, I think that the custom form created by HTML & Javascript can achieve your goal. But, python is not required to be used in this case. How about this? By the way, now, when you provide a simple sample scenario of your goal, I think that I can propose a sample script.

Comment: Thank you again for replying. Here is an example, assume that 'Linguistics' was not present in any of the choices in the sample form I proposed above(in the original question). So, I want to recommend it, and hence I write 'Linguistics' under the "Suggest a topic" field and submit. Now, if a new student or me open the form again then we must be able to see 'Linguistics' option under the 'Already Recommended' section. So, if someone is interested in 'Linguistics', they will directly select it instead of recommending again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your table in your question. So I cannot understand about your replying. I deeply apologize for this. In order to help to understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations using the images? By this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: I am sorry I was not able to reply yesterday. Thank you again for replying. I will post a picture of the form so that you can better understand the goal. Also, I am very thankful for your efforts.

Comment: For example, see this image [link](https://imgur.com/fHErxWO) here I am recommending a subject named 'Macro Economic', I don't know if Mr Hiroto knows about it, but I am just recommending. After recommending the form should look like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/Q4DLbcF) where the subject 'Macro Economics' appears under the already recommended section.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. I cannot understand about the logic for obtaining https://imgur.com/a/Q4DLbcF from https://imgur.com/fHErxWO . Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. And thank you again for replying to me. The logic behind the transition is that my professor want the subject to be available under Already recommended section so that student's don't end up recommending a same subject more than once.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I am extremely sorry I was caught up in some project and hence wasn't able to reply on time. Thank you for replying again. I wanted to say that, suppose student A wishes to study a subject, but no Professor is offering it. The form provides a field named 'Already recommended' so student A can check if his/her subject was recommended by someone else before or not. If it was, the (s)he would select directly, but if it wasn't then (s)he would recommend it. Now, if another student, say, student B opens the form, (s)he will find the subject recommended previously by student A.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: It is okay. Maybe, my problem statement is too vague or arbitrary. But, I thank you for your effort. I have seen that you are too good at apis because I have come across many of your answers while working with google and discord api. I think we might meet again in the future but with a different question. I am very grateful to you because of your other answers I used to debug/solve my problems. Also, I apologise for replying sloppily as there was some other work that occupied me.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think you are not wrong. I think that the reason I cannot understand your goal is due to my poor English skill. About this, I have to apologize. I would like to study more.